# Why is $\mathbb T\cup\mathbb A = \mathbb Q \cup \mathbb I =\mathbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

Where $\mathbb T $ is the set of transcendental numbers, and $\mathbb I $ is the set of irrational numbers and $\mathbb A $ is the set of algebraic numbers. The sets $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ have their usual meanings.

I'm having trouble understanding how the union of the transcendental $\mathbb T $ and algebraic numbers $\mathbb A $ is the same as the real numbers $\mathbb R$ since $\mathbb I ,\mathbb Q\subset\Bbb R$ as well.

Put in another way, I think it should be $( \mathbb T \cup \mathbb A) \subset \mathbb R $ and $(\mathbb Q \cup \mathbb I) \subset \mathbb R$

So I'm basically questioning the equality in $\mathbb T \cup \mathbb A  = \mathbb Q \cup \mathbb I =\mathbb R$.

The reason I'm asking this question is because those unions I mentioned above don't seem to 'cover' *all* the Reals $\mathbb R$ .

Thanks in advance.

Kindest Regards.

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ is usually defined as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{A}$, and similarly $\mathbb{I}$ is defined as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  With these definitions the equation must hold.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ supports all the symbols you left outside, that's what it's actually made for.

Comment: Uhm, $\mathbb A\cup\mathbb T=\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Lucian are you sure about that?

Comment: @Lucian The term *transcendental* has a more general meaning in field field, but usually by *transcendental number* one just means a real number that is not algebraic.

Comment: @user144533: *i*, for instance, is algebraic, since $x^2+1=0$ has $\pm i$ as its roots.

Comment: @Lucian Okay I see what you mean now thanks for taking time to explain that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a real number, if it is rational then it is in $\Bbb Q$, otherwise it is irrational and in $\Bbb I$. So $\Bbb{Q\cup I=R}$.

Similarly, if a real number is not algebraic then it is transcendental.

The set $\Bbb I$ is essentially defined as $\Bbb {R\setminus Q}$ and $\Bbb T$ is defined as $\Bbb{R\setminus A}$.

---

This is analogous to the following situation: Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers, and $Q$ the set of composite natural numbers. Let $E$ and $O$ denote the sets of even and odd name natural numbers respectively.

Then $\Bbb N=P\cup Q=E\cup O$. Just two partitions of the same sets.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am still confused why the unions in my question 'cover' *all* the Reals $\mathbb R$ .

Comment: Because if $Y$ is a subset of $X$ then $X=Y\cup(X\setminus Y) $.

Answer (score 6):

We *define* an irrational number to be a (real) number that isn't rational, which is equivalent to defining
$$\Bbb I := \Bbb R - \Bbb Q,$$
and hence
$$\Bbb Q \cup \Bbb I = \Bbb Q \cup (\Bbb R - \Bbb Q) = \Bbb R.$$It is correct, then, to say that $\Bbb Q \cup \Bbb I \subseteq \Bbb R$, but this statement contains less information than our equality.

The relationship between $\Bbb T$ and $\Bbb A$ is analogous.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I still don't quite understand why the unions in my question 'cover' *all* the Reals $\mathbb R$ .

Comment: For any set $X$ and subset $Y \subseteq X$, it is always true that $Y \cup (X - Y) = X$; this simply says that any element of $X$ is either in $Y$ or not in $Y$. In our case, we're just taking $X = \Bbb R$ and $Y = \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ha! I had the exact same reply to that comment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's essentially the very definitions of numbers involved.

$\Bbb Q$ is the set of all real numbers that can be expressed as the ratio if two integerss. We *define* a real number to be irrational if it's not rational, so that $\Bbb I = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ by definition, hence $\Bbb R = \Bbb Q \cup \Bbb I$.

Similarly, a real number is called algebraic (and is an element of $\Bbb A$) if it's the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. Those real numbers that aren't the root of any such polynomial are called transcendental, so that $\Bbb T = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb A$.

Note: many people consider some complex numbers to be algebraic as well (e.g., the imaginary unit $i$ is a solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$), so it might be more correct to say that $\Bbb R = (\Bbb A \cap \Bbb R) \cup \Bbb T$, considering $\Bbb A$ to be a subset of $\Bbb C$. Generally these people aren't terribly concerned with $\Bbb C \setminus \Bbb A$, so I'm not sure if these too are considered transcendental numbers, or just nameless. (I have character theory of finite groups in mind here.)

Comment: This is what I get for answering on a phone, being incredibly late to the party :)

Comment: I also answered from my phone! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, now I just feel slow! :P

Comment: Would it make things worse to say that I had also just woke up? :-P